# Проблема с jre, не может запустить Test connection

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, java

Пытаюсь протестить связь с бд и выпадает такая ошибка

```
Cannot run program "D:\Games\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\jre64\bin\java" (in directory "D:\Games\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Cannot run program "D:\Games\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\jre64\bin\java" (in directory "D:\Games\IntelliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Читал в гугле, везде только про jdk пишут, про jre ничего не нашел. Кто-то знает как решить?
Я так понял, что файл отсутствует. Как поменять jre?

**UPD** Вспомнил, что недавно обновлял jdk

**UPD2**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При том что скачал новый jre все равно осталась эта ошибка. Intellij почему-то ищет jre только в папке, в которой сам находится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осталось только в настройках указать путь к `jre`:

[image: скриншот]

А для уверенности можно еще в файле `{idea}/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn` прописать константу `JAVA_HOME - location of a JDK home dir`